# How to fully define an XML Schema for same element name but differing subtype

Tags: xsd

Hi again SO community,

got another request regarding how to define an XSD schema correctly.

Given I have an XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<transformation xmlns="http://www.denktmit.de/pdi/ktr" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
./test.xsd">
    <info>
        <name>TrafoName</name>
        <description>TrafoDescription</description>
    </info>
    <changedby>LastUser</changedby>
    <step>
        <type>FileInput</type>
        <description>FileInput Step description</description>
        <FileInputParameterOne>FileInputParam</FileInputParameterOne>
        <another>1</another>
    </step>
    <step>
        <type>Select</type>
        <description>Select Step description</description>
        <SelectParameterOne>SelectParameterOne</SelectParameterOne>
        <SelectParameterTwo>SelectParameterTwo</SelectParameterTwo>
        <another>2</another>
    </step>
</transformation>
```

This resembles the style of the transformation files as produced by http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/

As you can see, each step contains several sequence nodes on top

```
<type>Select</type>
<description>Select Step description</description>
```

and on bottom:

```
<another>2</another>
```

In between, arbitrary complex xml subtrees may occur. But what exactely max occur is determined by the value in "type". The use case is to store specific configurations for concrete Java classes, that all implement an interface, defining getters/setter for "type", "description" and "another" and defining addtional object structure themself. It would also be sufficient to neglect the order, as long as all the elements, needed for a specific class are somehow present.

I already read:

- [How to group types & subtypes in XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653120/how-to-group-types-subtypes-in-xsd)
- [xsd: How to extend a type with an unordered list of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808156/xsd-how-to-extend-a-type-with-an-unordered-list-of-elements)
- [Use <xs:all> in XML schema's complexType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603317/use-xsall-in-xml-schemas-complextype)
- [xsd: How to extend a type with an unordered list of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808156/xsd-how-to-extend-a-type-with-an-unordered-list-of-elements)

And I tried something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.denktmit.de/pdi/ktr" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns="http://www.denktmit.de/pdi/ktr">
    <xs:element name="transformation">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="step" type="fileInputStep"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="step" type="selectStep"></xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="stepComplexType" abstract="true"></xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="fileInputStep">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="stepComplexType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"
                        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="FileInputParameterOne" type="xs:string">
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="another" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="selectStep">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="stepComplexType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:pattern value="Select"></xs:pattern>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"
                        minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="SelectParameterOne"
                        type="xs:string">
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" name="SelectParameterTwo"
                        type="xs:string">
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="another" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But it is not working, telling me:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:   validation against this
>   schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
>     - Start tag of element 
>     - cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_transformation'. Multiple elements with name 'step', with different types, appear in
>   the model group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `xsd Group`. Here's an sample for your reference

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="transformation">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="step" type="stepType"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="stepComplexType" abstract="true"></xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="selectParamGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SelectParameterOne" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="SelectParameterTwo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="paramGroup">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="FileInputParameterOne" type="xs:string">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:group ref="selectParamGroup">
        </xs:group>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="stepType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="stepComplexType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string"></xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"
                    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
                <xs:group ref="paramGroup"></xs:group>
                <xs:element name="another" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<transformation>
<step>
    <type>FileInput</type>
    <description>FileInput Step description</description>
    <FileInputParameterOne>FileInputParam</FileInputParameterOne>
    <another>1</another>
</step>
<step>
    <type>Select</type>
    <description>Select Step description</description>
    <SelectParameterOne>SelectParameterOne</SelectParameterOne>
    <SelectParameterTwo>SelectParameterTwo</SelectParameterTwo>
    <another>2</another>
</step>
</transformation>
```